# "OperationalError at /admin/login/" showing old settings.py values

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new to Python and Django (coming from PHP background). I am trying to learn by Python/Django by doing and setup Django on EC2 and PostgreSQL on RDS.

I got the admin section set up and can see the login screen at /admin but once it is submitted I get a "OperationalError at /admin/login/" "unable to open database file" error. What is odd is the exception location is "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in get_new_connection, line 374" even though I setup PostgreSQL. Further down in the error it shows the settings.py file which doesn't reflect what I see on the server.

This is what the error shows:

```
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
         'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
         'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'HOST': '',
         'NAME': '/home/ubuntu/{folder}/project/db.sqlite3',
         'OPTIONS': {},
         'PASSWORD': u'************************',
         'PORT': '',
         'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                  'COLLATION': None,
                  'MIRROR': None,
                  'NAME': None},
         'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC',
         'USER': ''}}
```

But my setting.py file says this for database (with details removed of course):

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'USER': 'xxxxxxxxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'HOST': 'xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

Any idea? I've tried reloading apache, manage.py runserver, migrate and dbsync.

Comment: Check if ./manage.py diffsettings will display correct database connection settings (if any).

Comment: It displays the correct DB settings

Comment: So you clearly have to reload your app server (gunicorn, uwsgi etc).

Comment: Looks like that worked because it let me log in. Can you put this as an answer so I can give you credit?